# Where does MySQL store data?

Tags: mysql

Where does MySQL store data?

`SELECT @@datadir` returns var/lib/mysql - but that can't be it. I have a 4 GB database called bot, but all the files in the bot subdirectory (var/lib/mysql/bot) have only 280KB. Where is the rest?

99% of the database's size is a text column in one of the tables. MySQL stores it in separate files, but does it create one file per record?

I found a big file in the var/lib/mysql directory named ibdata1 - its size is over 8GB - what is it?

(There are other databases in the var/lib/mysql directory).

Comment: What storage engine are you using?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Reading between the lines - Is this an innodb database? In which case the actual data is normally stored in that directory under the name ibdata1. This file contains all your tables unless you specifically set up mysql to use one-file-per-table ([innodb-file-per-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html))

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I forgot to mention that it is innodb. You say that the file (ibdata1) "contains all the tables", but it looks like it actually contains all tables in all databases? Do you know whether  there is a reason for this? That seems stupid... And one more thing - can I change this option (innodb-file-per-table) now, when a database already exists and contains records?

Comment: Yes, Sorry should have said all databases. It is not really stupid see here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/why-does-innodb-store-all-databases-in-one-file. This option can only be changed by stopping mysql, changing the option, then restarting. Sorry but I have never tried to split innodb out, I would recommend using mysqldump to backup the DB(s), changing the option, then re-loading the DB(s).

Comment: Thank you! I'll certainly do it.

Answer (score 43):

From [here](http://www.mkyong.com/mysql/where-does-mysql-stored-the-data-in-my-harddisk/):

**Windows**

1. Locate the my.ini, which store in the MySQL installation folder.

For Example, `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini`

2. Open the “my.ini” with our favor text editor.

```
#Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/"
 
#Path to the database root
datadir="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/"
```

Find the `“datadir”`, this is the where does MySQL stored the data in Windows.

---

**Linux**

1. Locate the my.cnf with the find / -name my.cnf command.

```
yongmo@myserver:~$ find / -name my.cnf
find: /home/lost+found: Permission denied
find: /lost+found: Permission denied
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

2. View the `my.cnf` file like this: `cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
yongmo@myserver:~$ cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user   = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port   = 3306
basedir  = /usr
datadir  = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir  = /tmp
language = /usr/share/mysql/english
skip-external-locking
```

3. Find the `“datadir”`, this is where does MySQL stored the data in Linux system.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe you only read a title of my question, I did exactly what you described, but as I wrote in the post itself: "Where does mysql store data? I found out (by using mysql>SELECT @@datadir ) that it's in var/lib/mysql - but that can't be it. I have a quite big database (4 GB) called 'bot', but all the files in the 'bot' subdirectory (var/lib/mysql/bot) have only 280KB. Where is the rest?"

Comment: So find the data dir and locate the largest file or set of files, it's not that hard. Also, take a look at the other answer posted.

Comment: As I wrote, I located "ibdata1" file, but it's in the main directory, not in a subdirectory of a database, so it seemed impossible for me that this is the file I'm looking for.

Comment: Rather than using "find" on your whole filesystem, you can determine the datadir like this:  mysqld --verbose --help | grep datadir

Comment: In my case there is no "my.ini" file in the installation folder. I am using MySQL 8.0 & windows

Comment: I found it, the file was located under C:\ProgramData\MySQL, thus ProgramData and NOT ProgramFiles. ProgramData is a hidden folder btw. So under view (top left) in windows explorer you should select "show hidden items".

Answer (score 14):

In version 5.6 at least, the Management tab in MySQL Workbench shows that it's in a hidden folder called ProgramData in the C:\ drive. My default data directory is

> C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data

. Each database has a folder and each table has a file here.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed `MySQL Server 5.7` on `Windows 10` and `my.ini` file is located here `c:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini`.

The `Data` folder (where your dbs are created) is here `C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7\Data`.

Comment: Using this I was able to solve "mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1007 (HY000)".

Answer (score 1):

as @PhilHarvey said, you can use `mysqld --verbose --help | grep datadir`

Answer (score -1):

In mysql server 8.0, on Windows, the location is `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data`