# mysql - can't run commands in terminal?

Tags: mysql, sql, macos

I'm new to database and mysql.

After running `sudo mysql -u root -p` and type in my password, I get into mysql successfully. (I'm under Mac `OS X 10.10`.)

However, when I tried to create a database, there was something wrong.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 16
Server version: 5.6.23 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> create database test
    -> exit
    ->
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you may just be missing the semicolon

```
create database test;
```

Comment: Sorry to bother again. After I add a semicolon, a database is created and I can see it appears in the result of running `show databases;`. But where is the file? I run mysql under home directory but I can't find a database file in it?

Comment: I believe this will explain the location of the databases http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402884/where-does-mysql-store-data  I would suggest looking for a crash course type tutorial to get generally familiar with working with databases like maybe http://www.mysqltutorial.org