# MAMP how do I rescue my MySQL database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mamp

Apologies I am quite new at this, so the easier the better! I need to rescue a wordpress database from a corrupted MAMP installation.

This is the error I am receiving in the MySQL Log when I try and open MAMP:

https://codeshare.io/GqPykx

Thanks for any assistance!!

K

Answer (score 0):

You could start by applying the specified methods to restore to a known state.  If you're lucky you have permissions problem you just need to fix on the table storage files, if you're unlucky you should restore from your backup disk.

```
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./olivia/wp_term_taxonomy.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Comment: Any ideas on how I can fix permissions problem on the table storage files? I wouldn't know where to start.... :(

Comment: Locate your table files, location depends on your config http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402884/where-does-mysql-store-data, set all permissions to read write execute for your webserver's user.